# Is there any way to update bootstrap progress bar width from aspx.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have a button which open a modal pop up of bootstrap. In Modal Pop i show the progress of users action using bootstrap progress bar.

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" runat="server">
                CSV Upload <i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i>
            </asp:LinkButton>
            <UC:UCBulkUpload ID="ucBulkUpload" runat="server"></UC:UCBulkUpload>
```

After performing upload action in aspx.cs page i have update the progress to 100 % which i have code in javascript of same page inside script tag.

[image]

```
function endprogress() {
        document.getElementById('uploadprogress').classList.remove("w-50");
        document.getElementById('uploadprogress').classList.add("w-75");
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('uploadprogress').classList.remove("w-75");
            document.getElementById('uploadprogress').classList.add("w-100");
            document.getElementById('uploadprogress').innerHTML = "Upload Finished.";
        }, 500);
    }
```

i am calling the javascript fn from code behind using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "endprogress", "endprogress();", false);
```

But problem is that the modal pop up get closed during this call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of a postback to a .cs page is that the page is inevitably refreshed, which will reset your javascript including the popup. If you want to avoid the refresh while doing an operation on the server, you'll want to use AJAX to make the request to the server via javascript, rather than having the page do a postback.

Comment: Thanks you.

for a ajax call i have to make a [WebMethod] right ,  i will have to convert my btn_click to web service

Comment: Essentially yes, there's more than 1 way to implement, exactly how is up to you, but ultimately your btn_click code would be moved to a different page or a web method, something that you can call with ajax.

Comment: Thanks you , i hope this will help